# Making the window [X] button close instead of minimise on Windows Moblie

Tags: winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework

The [x] button in the top bar of a window that normally closes the window in standard Windows, appears to do a minimise instead on Windows Compact.

How do it make it close instead? I need to also be able to raise an event when this happens as I want to preform some logic on window close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the Form.MinimizeBox property to false. This will change the [X] to [ok], and close your form instead of minimizing it when clicked.

Edit: The event you want is either Closing or Closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this relates to the .NET forum support but you need to use the Native API [SHDoneButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa458082.aspx).

By default it's set to "`SHDB_HIDE`" which then shows the "Windows Mobile" "X" button (or any application that overrides X button like LGE's 'X' button application, or the HTC one).

If you set it to "`SHDB_SHOW`" it will show a "ok" button which sends a IDOK to the window if pressed.
If you set it to "`SHDB_SHOWCANCEL`" it will show a "x" button which sends a IDCANCEL to the window if pressed.  `SHDB_SHOWCANCEL` is not documented by MSDN but it's in the header file (aygshell.h).

Comment: Presumably the OP is asking how to do this in WinForms on Windows Mobile.